# Data for Auctions

Tags: data-request

Originally posted here:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85933/data-for-auctions
and was put on hold and suggested for this site.

Does anyone know how I can get a data feed for auction data? I would like to be able to display auctions local to users on my classifieds site. I've googled a lot but nothing is turning up. Something like adconnect.com is what I am looking for except for auctions and adconnect seemed to have very little data.

If I can get a data feed in some standard format I would be able to parse and display.

Also, if there is an easier way such as just including some HTML or javascript that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean auctions like eBay, or real life auctions? For eBay there are PIs you can use.